# What doen $f mean in jquery scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see the function $f being used in a number of jquery related scripts, but I can't find a description of what this means anywhere.

Example

```
var iframe = document.getElementById(iframe_id);
this.player = global.$f(iframe);
```

Can anyone point me to documentation?

Comment: There is no documentation, it's a custom variable of some sort.

Comment: Could be http://flowplayer.org but without seeing the project that is just a guess.

Comment: I would use Chrome's Inspect Element or Firefox's Firebox and enter `console.log(global.$f);` into it. This should at least give you a readout of what the variable is set to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently, `f$` is associated with [froogaloop](/questions/tagged/froogaloop), which is...

> (...) a small Javascript utility framework to help with the
>   complexities involved in dealing with using the Javascript API through
>   window.postMessage for controlling Vimeo's Moogaloop video player.

Answer (score 17):

`$F` is originally a function from [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/), returning the [value of the requested form element](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/dom/form.js#L733):

```
var $F = Form.Element.Methods.getValue;
```

From the [related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework):

> **The $F() function** - 
>   Building on the $() function: the $F() function returns the value of the requested form element. For a 'text' input, the function will return the data contained in the element. For a 'select' input element, the function will return the currently selected value.

It appears that plugin scripters have written a version for jQuery as well. [See this link here.](http://www.yonkenterprises.com/jQuery/plugins/F.html)

The flash video player Flowplayer [also has a function `$f`](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/flowplayer.html) that is a shortcut for `flowplayer()`.